# Localization on Mono for Android

Tags: c#, localization, xamarin.android

I did this example on Eclipse http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html, but how can I do it on Monodroid? I was researching and cannot find the same information for doing that. How does Localization work on Monodroid?

Comment: Could you explain why you tagged this "bugs"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono for Android uses the exact same resources as standard Android applications, so the same folder name conventions apply, including localization.

Comment: so if i do the same example from the android documentation on mono, it would works?

Comment: Yeah the same folder name conventions work. For example, Values-en for English, Values-es for Spanish, etc.